# Algebraic Proof of the Double - Dabble Method/Algorithms: Binary Numbers to Decimal Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have found a great book: Binary Arithmetics and Boolean Algebra by Angelo G. Gille. He is using a Double-Dablle Method to convert Binary Numbers to Decimal Numbers. 
Here is how its done. I have tried to understand/proove why its working. Maybe someone sees it? 
[image: img]
[image: img]

Comment: $101101$ is rather an unfortunate example, as the number is a palindrome, and so if a student/reader worked right-to-left instead of the correct left-to-right, s/he would get the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same as Horner's method for evaluating polynomials.
It works because

$$a_n2^n+a_{n-1}2^{n-1}+...+a_12+a_0=2(...(2(2(2a_n+a_{n-1})+a_{n-1})...+a_1)+a_0$$

If the formula in general looks obscure, you can try it for small values of $n$. For example, $n=3$:
$$2^3a_3+2^2a_2+2a_1+a_0=2(2(2a_3+a_2)+a_1)+a_0$$

Comment: Thank you, looks very nice!

Answer (score 3):

A similar thing occurs if someone reads you, digit-by-digit, left-to-right, a base ten numeral:

E.g. The actual numeral is $3702$, but you only get one digit at a time:

$3$. Current value is $3$.

$7$. Current the value is $3\cdot 10+7=37$.

$0$. Current the value is $37\cdot 10+0=370$.

$2$. Current the value is $370\times 10+2=3702$.

End of number.  The last current value is the actual value.

At each step, you multiply the previous total by the base and add the next digit.